# Can SSRS report be used to submit requests?

Tags: reporting-services

I have created a report for particular products which pulls up product number and types of products related to those product numbers. It is a very simple report where user is allowed to enter product number in a parameter which returns all the data related to this product. Main purpose for this report was to create pdf files for individual product numbers and all its data. So I decided to do data driven subscription to provide this functionality to the business users. Now, in the business requirement it says that "business submits request to pull 200 products and get a message saying "your request will be delivered to this particular folder within 24 hours" Now this is the part where I got confused. Can a report take request and display messages like that?

Requirements: 1.request is submitted by business to pull 200 producttypes let's say today. Then message is received "thank you for requesting. We will send an email to"[email address just entered] " when the report is ready. Files will be delivered to the following folder: [Path+date, time]" I don't know what email address he's talking about here I'm assuming he wants the report to accept emails when submitting the request. And date time on the folder path will the time request was submitter. 2. A job is kicked off to slowly deliver producttypes to the folder path. 3. Resulting file are places in a new subfolder named todaysdate+time. 4. Filename is productnumber. I have got the part down to create a report that has two columns productnumber and producttypes which has a data driven subscription that delivers files with productnumber name in folder. But I don't understand this message and request thing he's talking about. Also how to generate a subfolder depending on the time of the request. Thanks Daniel

Comment: Possibly by creating assemblies or dll & using them in SSRS not sure

Comment: SSRS reports are strictly for data demonstration, These reverencing requests and other event handling should be handled on application layer not in SSRS. Simply its Not possible.

Comment: If you don't understand the requirements, you should go back to the person submitting them for clarification otherwise you are unlikely to produce something that will meet the requirements. That said, data driven subscriptions will get the email address from the table you specify, however that table needs to be populated by some external process. I guess it would be possible to do this will a report but quite unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes
Report can handle this.
Please provide more details and I will work this out for you.

Daniel

Comment: I have added the requirements above. Let me know if u have other questions

Comment: I am interested to know how would you handle a request in SSRS? would you like to explain with an example what tools would you make use of to achieve this in SSRS?? Thank you

Comment: Ali - You are right RDL's are designed to present the information , -they can handle the requests ? yes and no  - this is not the proper way but If there is no choice this can be done on parameters passed to stored procedures when report is run - please let me know if I'm wrong - maybe I didn't catch the right concept  from the question.

Answer (score 0):

One way that comes to mind is by having two sets of reports and two stored procedures.
Report 1 and stored procedure1 would get the parameters and update the report data (see "When the report data is updated on the report server" option in the data driven subscription wizard) and the other report would then be executed and email/save the files in the required format.

Your first SP however needs to flag that your second report needs to be executed.